# change the database and the button state without refreshing the page - laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I have this list of companies and I want to activate/deactivate them using a button without refreshing the page, so when I press the "activate/deactivate" button the state of the company changes and the button also changes from activate to deactivate and vice versa.

this is the button the view of the list :

```
<!-- entreprises datatable-->
<div class="panel-body">
    <table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>RS</th>
                <th>Secteur</th>
                <th>Telephone</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           @foreach($resultas as $resultat)
           <tr>
               <td>{{ $resultat->id}}</td>
               <td style="width:100%">{{ $resultat->RS}}</td>
               <td>{{ $resultat->secteur}}</td>
               <td>{{ $resultat->Tel1}}</td>
               <td style=" display:flex">
                   <div><a href="{{ route('CP_edit',['id'=> $resultat->id]) }}"><button style="background-color:#584F6C" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"> Modifier</button></a></div>
                   <div>
                       @if( $resultat->active == 0 )
                   <a href="{{ route('CP_activate', ['id'=> $resultat->id, 'activation'=> $resultat->active]) }}"><button  style="background-color:#3CB371; margin-left:20px;" name="activation" value="{{ $resultat->active }}" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"> Activate</button></a>
                       @else
                       <a href="{{ route('CP_activate', ['id'=> $resultat->id, 'activation'=> $resultat->active ]) }}"> <button  style="background-color:#B22222; margin-right:20px;" name="activation" value="{{ $resultat->active }}" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"> Deactivate</button></a>
                       @endif
                   </div>
                </td>
           </tr>
           @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

and this is the controller function that changes the status of the company :

```
public function CP_activate(Request $request)
{
    $state = $request->activation;
    $info = entreprise::find($request->id);

    if( $state == 1)
    {
        $info->active = 0;

        $info->save();
    }

    if( $state == 0)
    {
        $info->active = 1;

        $info->save();
    }
}
```

I am using the POST method, and I don't know if I should switch to GET or not .
if you have any idea on how to get this to work please .

Comment: Could you share what the javascript function `activate` is doing ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti it's doing nothing it is still empty

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Javascript ajax instead of using `<a>` anchor tag

check

1. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

also if you using vue.js or any other frontend framework check its implementation for ajax requests

Answer (score 1):

So, the best way of doing so is to do an AJAX request instead of a plain Form.

So, based on your Blade template, you already have a JS function listening the clicking of the button/link to toggle it.

Assuming your function is redirecting/refreshing your page, you have to do this:

1. Your function should not be sending the element itself, as if you don't send anything you are already receiving the `Event` and it holds the element that triggered it.
2. So your function should be like `onclick="activate"` and it should work.
3. On your function declaration, you should have this:

```js
function activate(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // <--- this is the magic part that will not go to that URL or refresh the page
    /* now you should do an AJAX call to that URL with the data you want,
     * so if you want to read the value or anything about that <a> tag, you
     * can do event.target and is the same as your previous "this"
     */
}
```

4. Your controller code could be simplified but it has a "downside":

```php
public function CP_activate(Request $request)
{
    $info = entreprise::find($request->id);

    $info->active = !$info->active;
    $info->save();
}
```

The "downside" is that if you open multiple pages (same page multiple times), and you click on the button, it will **TOGGLE** the active state instead of telling it what state to have, but it is way less code, simplified and it is super strange for someone to have the same page open twice or more...

Anyway, please share your `activate` JS function !

Comment: the activate function is really not doing anything i just put it there so i can start working on it ... i am still a beginner when it comes to Js and AJAX.
about the downside you said i didn't understand please can you tell me more !

Comment: Yes, the "downside" with my point 4 is that if you open that page in multiple tabs (at least twice), let's say you will have 2 tabs both in the same state (let's say ACTIVE), in the first tab, you click on it so it TOGGLES to DEACTIVE, but if you see the second tab and you click again, the state of that current tab is ACTIVE but your database has DEACTIVE, so when you click it, it will switch again to ACTIVE and the button will show DEACTIVE but it was ACTIVE (you will have to refresh the page to see the real state in that case), do you follow me ? Still, it would be easier to use my code

Comment: so all i need to do is add this to my controller function : 

$info->active = !$info->active;

Comment: If you want to make that code more readable, simple and smaller, yes, but that will not make your blade/javascript work out of the box, you still have to implement the AJAX call in the Blade template as Mohamed answered how to ! You can also read more about [Form Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation) so your code would shrink to 2 lines of code

Comment: thank you so much .. i will add that "  $info->active = !$info->active; " to the controller to prevent the downside you explained and i will work on the ajax

Comment: Maybe you missunderstood what I said, but using my simplified controller code will create this downside, the way to fix it is to reply with the new state, so your Javascript code (that sent the AJAX request) will see the new state that is saved and you can then put a check, mark or whatever you are using to show the user the current state in the right state. You can do this, work on your code, have a "final code" to show us and leave a comment, so we can continue guiding you in small steps ! If you do so, edit your question on top adding or updating your code